# Browser is able to load website only at the second attempt

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

I get a weird error with my webpage once in a while when trying to reload the page and Google Chrome throws `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to subdomain.mydomain.com`.

Then I refresh the page and it works. This doesn't happen on every second request, but just once a while. Any ideas? Could it be related to Ubuntu? I tried working with different browser, but this still occurs. So I guess it's not browser related but rather OS related. 
Also for everyone else in the office the webpage loads without connection errors. They run on Windows though.

Comment: How do you know it's not website related? Does it only happen to this subdomain?

Comment: Yes and it only occurs to me. For the rest 15 colleagues it works fine.

Comment: Do you use any Anti Virus/ Internet Security / Anti banner type of plug in / software?

Comment: Not that I know of any.